# Synchronization of the SQLite database with nexusDB

Tags: sqlite, delphi, vcl, nexusdb

I want to create a mobile application, which has SQLite as databases (on mobile app) and nexusDB is the central database, which contains all the company data. I would like to synchronize SQLite (I use DB Browser for SQLite) with nexusdb and I don't know how to get there.

Thanks for our help.

Comment: See comment [here](https://nexusdb.com/forums/showthread.php?t=17329&styleid=20) which suggests using UniDAC to write your own converter on the basis that it supports NexusdB and Sqlite.

Comment: With an ORM, it could be easier.

Comment: Where  and how can I find and use  ORM ? Is it inside of NexusDB ?